# Thread cancellation before calling join() gives an error

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, cancellation

The [POSIX Standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02) reads that

> The lifetime of a thread ID ends after the thread terminates if it was created with the detachstate attribute set to PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED or if pthread_detach() or pthread_join() has been called for that thread.

In the following program a single thread is created. This thread executes the `thread_task()` routine. After the routine is done, the thread exits but, because its detachstate attribute is **PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE** (by default), I would expect calling `pthread_cancel()` on this thread to be safe and not return any error. *It's kinda lengthy because of extensive error checking*

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int counter=0;

void free_buffer(void* buff)
{
    printf("freeing buffer\n");
    free(buff);
}

void* thread_task(void* arg)
{
    void* buffer = malloc(1000);
    pthread_cleanup_push(free_buffer, buffer);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { // 'counter' is a global variable
        for(counter = 0; counter < 10000; counter++);
        pthread_testcancel();
    }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    printf("Thread exiting\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int errnum = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_task, NULL);
    if(errnum != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create(): %s\n", strerror(errnum));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    getchar();

    errnum = pthread_cancel(tid);
    if(errnum != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_cancel(): %s [%d]\n", strerror(errnum), errnum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    void* ret;
    errnum = pthread_join(tid, &ret);
    if(errnum != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(): %s [%d]\n", strerror(errnum), errnum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    if(ret == PTHREAD_CANCELED) {
        printf("Thread was canceled\n");
    }

    printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
}
```

This doesn't happen however. When I run the program the messages I see are:

```
// wait for the thread routine to finish...
freeing buffer
Thread exiting
// press any key
pthread_cancel(): No such process [3]
```

This seems to suggest that after the thread exits, its TID is no longer valid. Doesn't this go against the standard? What's going on here?

Comment: FWIW: I was able to run your program after adding four `#include ...` lines and a global declaration for `int counter`. It did not behave in the same way that you described. My environment: Apple clang 13.0.0, on an ARM-based Mac, running macOS 11.6. I didn't see any error message, regardless of whether the cancel call happened before or after the thread reached the end of `thread_task()`. What build toolchain are _you_ using? On what platform are you running it?

Comment: I first ran it on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 (compiled with GCC 9.3.0). For the second time I ran it on Arch Linux (compiled with GCC 11.1.0). Got the same output each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the IEEE standard, but IMO, the man pages "[pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)," and "[pthread_cancel(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)" are ambiguous.

The pthread_cancel man page only gives one possible error code, ESRCH, which supposedly means, "No thread with the ID *thread* could be found." But notice, it says, "No thread...could be found" It doesn't say, "No such ID exists."

The pthreads(7) man page guarantees that the *ID* of a non-detached thread remains valid and unique until that ID is `join()`ed, but it doesn't say anything about whether the thread itself continues to "exist" (in the sense that pthread_cancel() cares about) just because its ID continues to exist.

I ran the OP's code on a different platform, and `pthread_cancel()` did *not* return an error for me, even long after the thread had returned from the `thread_task()` function.
IMO, there's cases to be made for both OP's build toolchain and mine to be "correct" in the sense of, "compliant with the man pages."

---

> I would expect calling pthread_cancel() on this thread to be safe and not return any error.

What does "safe" mean? To me, pthread_cancel() would be "safe" if it was possible to create a guaranteed reliable program that uses it. If you had to assume that either behavior is possible, that complicates things, but I don't think it makes the task *impossible.* IMO the worst it does is limit what kind of information you can gain from reading the errors if your program bothers to log them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that if you are not fast enough, the thread finishes by itself (consuming all the loops) before you type RETURN on the keyboard. So, `pthread_cancel()` ends in error because you are trying to cancel a thread which is terminated. But the following `pthread_join()` succeeds to reap the thread. With `strace`, you get an idea on what happens:

```
$ strace -f ./pcancel
execve("./pcancel", ["./pcancel"], 0x7ffd11e1ad58 /* 28 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55cf92027000
[...]

#### CREATION OF THE THREAD ==> Linux task id: 10679

clone(child_stack=0x7fe663b19fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fe663b1a9d0, tls=0x7fe663b1a700, child_tidptr=0x7fe663b1a9d0) = 10679
strace: Process 10679 attached

[pid 10678] fstat(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 10679] set_robust_list(0x7fe663b1a9e0, 24 <unfinished ...>
[pid 10678] <... fstat resumed> {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 13), ...}) = 0
[pid 10679] <... set_robust_list resumed> ) = 0

#### Main thread is waiting for a char on the keyboard (getchar() call)

[pid 10678] read(0,  <unfinished ...>

#### Meanwhile the thread continues its execution...

[pid 10679] mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7fe65b31a000
[pid 10679] munmap(0x7fe65b31a000, 13524992) = 0
[pid 10679] munmap(0x7fe660000000, 53583872) = 0
[pid 10679] mprotect(0x7fe65c000000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
[pid 10679] fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 13), ...}) = 0
[pid 10679] write(1, "freeing buffer\n", 15freeing buffer
) = 15
[pid 10679] write(1, "Thread exiting\n", 15Thread exiting
) = 15
[pid 10679] madvise(0x7fe66331a000, 8368128, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0

#### The thread finishes here...

[pid 10679] exit(0)                     = ?
[pid 10679] +++ exited with 0 +++

#### Main thread reads the char on the keyboard

<... read resumed> "\n", 1024)          = 1

#### The call to pthread_cancel() fails because the thread is already finished

write(2, "pthread_cancel(): No such proces"..., 38pthread_cancel(): No such process [3]
) = 38
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

If you type RETURN twice very quickly after the launching your program, `pthread_cancel()` will have a chance to be called by the main thread before the secondary thread finishes:

```
$ ./pcancel [RETURN typed twice very quickly]

freeing buffer
Thread was canceled
counter = 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn't happen however. When I run the program the messages I see are:
>
> ```
> // wait for the thread routine to finish...
> freeing buffer
> Thread exiting
> // press any key
> pthread_cancel(): No such process [3]
> ```

On my Linux machine I can observe that behavior, but if I am quick enough then I can also observe:

```
freeing buffer
Thread was canceled
counter = 10000
```

One way I was able to see that was by redirecting `/dev/null` into the program's standard input.

> This seems to suggest that after the thread exits, its TID is no longer valid.

Not so fast.  All you know is that `pthread_cancel()` failed, and that it chose `ESRCH` to characterize the reason for the failure.  POSIX does recommend that return value in the case that a TID is passed to `pthread_cancel()` after its (the TID's) lifetime ends, but you seem to be reading too much into that.  POSIX places no requirements at all on why the function might fail or what error code(s) it should return if it does, and it especially does not reserve that particular error code for the case that the TID is invalid.  It does not follow from the error code alone that the TID was invalid or that its lifetime had ended.

In fact, if I remove the `exit()` call in the event that `pthread_cancel()` fails, I can observe `pthread_join()` succeeding with the same TID, which strongly suggests that the TID was still valid at the point of the join.

> Doesn't this go against the standard? What's going on here?

If the TID's lifetime in fact ended before the thread it identified was joined, then that would be contrary to spec, but I see no reason to think that happened.  What appears to be going on is that your `pthread_cancel()` implementation is failing for threads that have already terminated, whether they have yet been joined or not.  The spec does not speak directly to the terminated but unjoined case, but the behavior seems reasonable to me: the thread cannot act on a cancellation request because it is no longer running.  That does not preclude that some other implementation might succeed under the same circumstances -- not every behavioral detail is specified or consistent across implementations.

> I would expect calling `pthread_cancel()` on this thread to be safe and not return any error.

I don't see why.  In the first place, "safe" and "[will] not return any error" are not at all the same thing.  They're not even very closely related.  `pthread_cancel()` is *not* safe, and it generally should not be used, but that has to do with its semantics, not with whether it may fail.  Lots of functions that are much safer will fail under some circumstances. Indeed, that they report to you when they do fail is one of the things that makes them safe(r).

Comment: Re, "the thread cannot act on a cancellation request because it is no longer running." Agreed, that this falls within spec, but IMO it would be better if it did not return an error. After all, the reason I am "cancelling" a thread is because I want it to terminate. If it terminated on its own before I sent the request, that is arguably a success. I wanted the thread to terminate, and it is terminated.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, I understand your perspective.  I'm honestly not sure which approach I prefer myself. I rarely think about it, in part because I consider it mooted by an important principle of pthreads development: never call `pthread_cancel()`.

Comment: Touché! I should have seen that, and I should have asked the OP "why cancel?"